# Symfony EntityType - how to hide values?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I am rendering a form with EntityType field, like this:

```
        $builder
        ->add('categoryId',EntityType::class,array('class' => 'TestBundle:BudgetCategory','choice_label'=>'description'))
        //etc...
```

And now it is displaying all possible options.

But my BudgetCategory entity contains also "hidden" field, and I prefer not to display options with hidden value set to true.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EntityType` has option `query_builder` which lets you [customize which entities are fetched](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities)

It would be something like:

```
->add('categoryId',EntityType::class,array(
    'class' => 'TestBundle:BudgetCategory',
    'choice_label'=>'description',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
                  ->where('b.hidden = 1');
     },
))
```